# Print c with gcc and c++ with g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Can anybody tell how to write a program which when compiled with `gcc` prints `c` , and with `g++` prints `c++`?

Comment: why negative , is it a wierd question?

Comment: Why was it closed as not real? I would understand duplicate, but not this.

Comment: It's vague. The OP could mean about 3 things with the question.

Comment: You actually asked the basis of an interesting question, that would apply more to header files. If a C file has a .c extension, you know what it is, but if a header file is included in C file, you would need                                                        `#if __cplusplus
    printf("c++");
#else printf("c");`  However, you would not have a header file call print (at least under most circumstances). This approach is so C++ files do not name mangle C functions, like being imported from a DLL (Windows) or a C library.

Comment: @akash The downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", the first is true. Some people also downvote because a question seems to basic... which is stupid IMHO.

Comment: @drise: what 3 different things? I can see it in only one way.

Comment: @akash - Maybe you can clarify a little. Are you trying to print "c" or are you trying to do something more like my answer below and have a common print used for C and C++? I may need to tweak my answer depending

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    printf("c++\n");
#else
    printf("c\n");
#endif
```

You may run into issues if your file extension isn't right.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
#if __cplusplus
    printf("c++");
#else 
    printf("c");
#endif
```

Unless you're compiling with `g++ -x c` which it will still print C even though compiled with g++.  That's a gotcha.

Comment: I think it's missing an `#endif`.

Comment: This way of formatting preprocessor directives confuses the hell out of me. Even if I mentally add the `#endif`. It may be valid and all, but it still feels wrong...

Comment: I have now fixed those issues

Comment: I'm curious.  You appear to have voted to close the question as "Not a real question".  But if it's not a real question, how were you able to answer it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I did that before I really understood what OP was asking.

Answer (score 5):

The treatment of the `struct` tags differs between C and C++

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef int T;

int main(void) {
  struct T { int a[2]; };
  puts((sizeof(T) > sizeof(int)) ? "C++" : "C");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using one of the differences between C and C++. (Will do the wrong thing on an implementation with sizeof(int) == 1)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("c%s\n", (sizeof('a') == 1 ? "++" : ""));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, I don't think you mean literally `how do you print 'C' or 'C++'`; but I'm reading it as `how do you execute a print in either C or C++ depending on the compiler`

Assuming that's what you're asking, you can give this a try:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus                //If you compiled with g++
#include <iostream>                 //include c++ headers and namespace
using namespace std;
#define PRINT(str)  cout << str;    //print the message with cout
#else                             //If you compiled with gcc
#include <stdio.h>                  //include c headers 
#define PRINT(str)  printf(str);    //print using printf
#endif 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PRINT("Hello\n");            //Whatever you compiled with, this now works
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If that was the question, he could skip all the conditional preprocessor stuff and just use printf, since that's available in both languages.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - OP **could** use just `printf()` but then OP is missing the benfits of `cout`. I'm thinking right now about `cout` knowing types dynamically so you don't have the extra `%` fields in there, thus making it less error prone.